# UNET prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I use unet for image segmentation my question is what does below code mean

```
test_img_norm=test_img[:,:,0][:,:,None]
```

and

```
prediction_other = (model.predict(test_img_other_input)[0,:,:,0] > 0.2).astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About first question `test_img_norm=test_img[:,:,0][:,:,None]`,  `test_img[:,:,0]` will copy first channel of image and `test_img[:,:,0][:,:,None]` will add one channel to it. for example if you have an image with shape `(256, 256, 3)`, `test_img_norm` shape will be `(256, 256, 1)`.

About second part of question, `model.predict(test_img_other_input)[0,:,:,0] > 0.2` will give you a boolean array. For every element in output of UNet, if element is less than 0.2, output would be `True`, otherwise would be `False`. And finally `.astype(np.uint8)` make booleans to zero or one.